# require won't load variables from current file

Tags: php

I am trying to require a header page inside my index but it won't load the variables with it.

Inside my object:

```
public function autoload($foo, array $bar = array()) {
    $Ar = array();
    $Ar['Page-Title'] = $bar['Page-Title'];
    $Ar['Header-Requires'] = $bar['Header-Requires'];
    require_once $this->BaseDIR . $foo;
}
```

Inside my index page:

```
$Ar = array();
$Ar['Page-Title'] = 'Homepage';
$Obj->autoload('header.php', $Ar);
```

The header page is loaded but this line is not run (line 1) on the file:

```
// test
echo $Ar['Page-Title'];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe $bar['Header-Requires'] is not defined? there is no such index. have you turned on errors?

Comment: Removed it but nothing and yes, `error_repporting(1);` is on the index page @EdgarsAivars

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function autoload($foo, $bar = array()) {
    $Ar = array();
    $Ar['Page-Title'] = $bar['Page-Title'];
    $Ar['Header-Requires'] = $bar['Header-Requires'];
    require_once $this->BaseDIR . $foo;
}
```

index page:

```
$Ar = array();
$Ar['Page-Title'] = 'Homepage';
$Ar['Header-Requires'] = true;
$Obj->autoload('header.php', $Ar);
```

In header:

```
var_dump($Ar);
```

Comment: will try it soon, havent got around to continuing the development today so when I get on laptop will let you know - thanks in advance though, hopefully it is not null haha